# Incompatible runner: NAnt

Tags: nant, teamcity-5.0

I installed TeamCity 5.03 on my windows machine a while ago and it worked fine until I installed Visual Studio 2010. After installing it, I get the above error message and none my projects are working. Does anybody know how to fix this? Please note that I already set the %env.NAntHome% to the path of my nant bin folder. I also set the env.NAntHome variable in my buildAgent.properties file.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I had to set the DotNetFramework for nant. You can do that in the buildAgent.properties, which is in /buildAgent/conf/. I added the following line:

system.DotNetFramework2.0